# Cloudbees build error

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, cloudbees

I am trying to deploy my project on cloudbees but I am getting following errors (It used to work before properly.)

So before posting here I tried several solutions but nothing seems to work. The only thing I observed in comparison of old and new log is there is change of version of plexus-classworlds. Previously it was **plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar** now it is seen as **plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar**. Could this be a problem?

Error log is as follows:

```
$ /opt/jdk/jdk1.7.latest/bin/java -cp /scratch/jenkins/maven3-agent.jar:/opt/maven/latest/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main /opt/maven/latest /scratch/jenkins/slave.jar /scratch/jenkins/maven3-interceptor.jar 51979
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.BooleanConverter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Executing Maven:  -B -f /scratch/jenkins/workspace/sampleProj/sample-admin/pom.xml clean install -Pdevci,allTests
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:100)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:66)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenLoggerManager
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:73)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.cli.MavenLoggerManager
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
    ... 19 more
channel stopped
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
hudson.util.IOException2: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:162)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:66)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:161)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:100)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenLoggerManager
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:73)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.cli.MavenLoggerManager
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: Why is down voting? Explanation would be great.

Answer (score 5):

[JENKINS-15935](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15935) is fixed [as of the 1.509.4 LTS release](http://jenkins-ci.org/changelog-stable). CloudBees DEV@Cloud Jenkins is a patched version of 1.509.2 at the moment. The Maven integration in this release is not compatible with Maven 3.1. Unless your job explicitly requires Maven 3.1, you can simply downgrade to 3.0.5 (`Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Maven installations`) and it should work.

[image: CloudBees Maven 3.0.5]

What I've heard from CloudBees is that a Jenkins update is coming soon (maybe a CloudBees official can comment on the matter).

Comment: You can now upgrade your DEV@cloud Jenkins to 1.509.4 by restarting it. PS, thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 0):

It must be related to Maven 3.1.0. Check this out:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15935